# Aspects of September 24, 2020 US House Energy Bill that US Rep. Kinzinger characterized as "barriers to energy use and development"?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, nuclear-energy, energy-policy, energy-independence

The October 7, 2020 video [Kinzinger: Addressing the Issues of Clean Energy, Now and for the Future #NuclearMatters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92Gnkfd9U6E) on US House member Adam Kinzinger (R-IL) YouTube channel discusses a "partisan bill" brought "to the House Floor for a vote on September 24, 2020."

Here is my transcription of the closed captions in the video:

After about `01:37` Kinzinger says:

> I also saw it a s the perfect vehicle to advance my bill and other pro-nuclear policies. Unfortunately, that’s not what happened, and I ultimately voted against Speaker Pelosi’s highly partisan bill.
>
> Frankly, there were some good policies in the bill — even ones that I’ve long supported. **But like so many times over the past two years, Speaker Pelosi took a series of hard-wrought, bipartisan measures from Energy and Commerce and other committees, and lumped them together with a wish-list of partisan priorities that tacks on over $100 billion to the deficit and adds massive new regulatory burdens.**
>
> If you take a macro-level view of this package, you’ll see it’s actually somehow divided against itself. It sets up a number of “moonshot” goals and programs to foster breakthrough in innovation in energy development; these are things we should all be able to get behind.
>
> But at the same time, it creates a litany of new regulatory and legal barriers to energy use and development.
>
> ...President Kennedy...moonshot...unicorns...
>
> This approach — people pushing through policies according to their emotions and without building consensus — is not doing the hard work. It’s not legislating. It’s not a “moonshot.” It’s called “virtue signaling”.
>
> And without clear objectives and removing as many barriers as possible, it’s a wasted effort because it’s not going to amount to much scientific breakthrough.
>
> Speaker Pelosi and Democrat Leadership in the House had every opportunity to craft a strong, bipartisan package. But that’s not what we voted on.

**Question:** What bill was this exactly, and what parts of it is Kinzinger referring to that "creates a litany of new regulatory and legal barriers to energy use and development"? Specifically what parts of the bill are likely to be those that Kinzinger characterizes as "barriers to energy use and development"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What bill was this exactly, and what parts of it is Kinzinger referring to that "creates a litany of new regulatory and legal barriers to energy use and development"? Specifically what parts of the bill are likely to be those that Kinzinger characterizes as "barriers to energy use and development"?

Bill: [H.R.4447 - Clean Economy Jobs and Innovation Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/4447)

Congressional Record: [EXPANDING ACCESS TO SUSTAINABLE ENERGY ACT OF 2019](https://www.congress.gov/116/crec/2020/09/24/CREC-2020-09-24-pt1-PgH4898-6.pdf)

Committee Report: [H. Rept. 116-504](https://www.congress.gov/116/crpt/hrpt504/CRPT-116hrpt504.pdf)

When H.R.4447 was reported to the House on September 15, 2020, [the bill was 12 pages](https://www.congress.gov/116/bills/hr4447/BILLS-116hr4447rh.pdf) as "Expanding Access to Sustainable Energy Act of 2019".

When referred to the Senate, [the bill was 1206 pages](https://www.congress.gov/116/bills/hr4447/BILLS-116hr4447rfs.pdf) as "Clean Economy Jobs and Innovation Act".

During the floor debate on H.R.4447, six amendments were added. The first amendment [H.Amdt.888](https://www.congress.gov/amendment/116th-congress/house-amendment/888?s=a&r=6) replaced the text that was reported to the House with text from a Rules Committee report. Then five amendments, each of which contained blocks of amendments were added – nearly 100 in total.

As a mere mortal, identifying the specific parts of the bill that would complete the answer to the question is beyond my ability. However, a reading of the Congressional Record would provide a reasonable start; that is only 52 pages.

Comment: Interestingly at `04:06` [Kinzinger complained](https://youtu.be/92Gnkfd9U6E?t=245) about "dozens of amendments" being voted down by the speaker. Are you sure it's amendments and not the original bill?